# Excel - Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Context:

I am exporting data from a database as a .csv file, copying it to a master workbook, formatting the data then copying the formatted data to another sheet.

Erroneous code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

Shown in below:

```
    Sub weekly_export_cleanup()
'
' weekly_export_cleanup Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:L").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("J:K").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("K:Q").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="(PO", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range( _
        "D1:D15"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = _
        RGB(255, 199, 206)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should split that line up, there are too many dots. When you get this error you don't know which of the six parts is failing. cf [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: Try to change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @AndyG The code above was auto-generated by excel as I recorded this macro

Comment: @JohnyL No luck, same error at the same place.

Comment: Are you throwing Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range or Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set?

Comment: I'm presuming that you still have `Sheet3` in your workbook?

Comment: @user10735198 it was an "error 9"

Comment: @Zac - AH! the tab was changed from "Sheet3" to "export". Such a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Np, glad it helped